# force open android app through schema

Tags: android, android-intent, schema, uri, deep-linking

Here is my story. I have an android app that shares my website link. on Android devices I want to check if the user has my android app open android application and show corresponding content to that link, but if do not have my app open up that link in the browser. I use [DeepLinkDispatch](https://github.com/airbnb/DeepLinkDispatch) for this, but I have a problem, when user click on shared link, android ask client to choose which app open this link (include my app), but i want to force open my app. (if installed on device)

Comment: try and edit your question, it's difficult to understand what you're really after.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

That is not possible prior to Android 6.0.

On Android 6.0+, you can can use [automatic verification of app links](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html#request-verify) to request that your app be the one to handle certain URLs, when they are used in `ACTION_VIEW` `Intents`.

However:

- A Web browser does not have to use `ACTION_VIEW` for a URL. A Web browser is welcome to just load the Web page identified by the URL.
- I do not know if app link verification works for `Intent` actions other than `ACTION_VIEW`. Your question suggests that the URL might be used in `ACTION_SEND` instead.
- Users can go into Settings and prevent your app from handling URLs.

Comment: thank you, i understand it but i have another question, when i open up telegram channel link, it goes to it's website and automatically open up mobile app without asking client. so my question how this work? (even on android pre 6.0)

Comment: @MostafaDavodi: The only way to open a link in an app, that is "guaranteed" to only go to that app, is if the link is not honored by anything else. Since all `http` and `https` URLs will be honored by Web browsers, this means that you would need to use a custom schema (e.g., `telegram`). Telegram, in particular, has activities that support `tg` and `tgb` schemes. However, many apps will not honor such URLs. For example, an SMS client might not recognize that `tg://...` is a URL and make it clickable.

Comment: @MostafaDavodi: More importantly, this does not support your requirements ("but if do not have my app open up that link in the browser"). A Web browser might be willing to try `ACTION_VIEW` to launch an app, when it encounters a link to a `tg://...` URL. However, if there is no app installed for that, the browser has no way to automatically map that to some `https` URL to bring up a Web page.

Comment: i understand that we can use a custom schema to load just my app but for example in telegram, when you click on channel link it goes to website and if app was install in device open it directly and if not, open up telegram website.

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the intent category, default and browsable with  android:scheme, android:host and android:pathPrefix in the activity intent filter in the manifest file with action view. 
For example if the url is : “http://www.example.com/gizmos”. Based on the host, scheme and path prefix in the data android will find the intent that can handle the url.  To enable the os to find your intent you have to add following filter in the app.

```
<activity
android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_title_viewgizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
    <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
    <data android:scheme="example"
          android:host="gizmos" />
</intent-filter>
```

**Test the deep link:** You can test the deeplink from shell as follows:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "http://www.example.com/gizmos" packageIDofYourApp
```

You can dig deeper on deplinking at [developer site](https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html)

**Verify if your App can receive the intent** You can check if your app can handle the intent having the specific url using package manager:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.example.com/gizmos"));

    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(intent,
            PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
    boolean isIntentSafe = activities.size() > 0;
    System.out.println("print pack:"+ ((isIntentSafe == true) ? activities.get(0).activityInfo.packageName : "No package found"));
```

Comment: i implement this part, i just want to force device to open up my app without asking client to choose it.