# Unique identificator for intent filter when handling deep links

Tags: android, deep-linking

I've defined my deep links as following:

```
<activity android:name=".x"        
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:parentActivityName=".x">

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="*.x.lv"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
            <data android:scheme="https"
                android:host="*x.lv"
                android:pathPrefix="/x" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

How can I add "unique" id for `intent-filter`? Action does not cut it, because `"android.intent.action.VIEW"` can be used for different reasons and that does not give me full trust in saying that this intent is for `deep-links` and nothing else. Any ideas?

Comment: From which domain or link do you want to launch your app?

Comment: @RutvikBhatt What do you mean? Link or domain should not be required in any sense of what I am asking (maybe you can expand on your question). I'm looking for a way to make deep link intent unique with some id, label or something.

Comment: You need to define prefix hostname in manifest file like this `<data android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPrefix="/xy"
                    android:scheme="https" />`  so now when you click on https://example.com/xy , your app will be one of the option to open app

Comment: You can define multiple `intent-filter` in single activity but not make unique link each time. If you need this use [Firebase DynamicLinks](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/)

Comment: So basically, there's no way (not using 3rd parties) of really checking if specific intent-filter is from a `deeplink` as the action: `"android.intent.action.VIEW"` can be from other intents as well?

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41075744/6454463) may help you about your question